# Short story - man obsessed with news, then lives solitary life, then goes on killing rampage

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember reading a short story about a married couple where a man was always obsessed with the news (I think it was on the radio) until his wife was so exasperated with him she nagged him and drove him away. Much later he was found living a solitary life (I think in the mountains) and now just happy to be left alone to play his cello. Eventually he was talked into returning to a normal life, and he soon goes on a rampage killing people. It is not a recent story, I read this about 50 years ago.
Does this sound familiar to anyone--who wrote it and the name of the short story?